# htaccess rewrite rule for a cms website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi I am trying to  write a re write rule for a cms website.

This is the sample url that im trying to.

http://www.website.com/residential/search_property?reload=true&community_sel=US

And i need to rewrite this url to something like,

http://www.website.com/residential/US

I tried the below rule, but that dint worked. Any idea?

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ residential/search_property?reload=true&community_sel=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you enter in the first part is accessible in the rewrite path using $1, $2 and so on. So in your RewriteRule community_sel should be $2 not $1

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /residential/search_property?reload=true&community_sel=$2
```

If you want "residential" directory to be rewritten as well then you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /$1/search_property?reload=true&community_sel=$2
```

Comment: That too not working.  This is the original url that I am working with. http://www.nosnownaples.com/residential/search_property?reload=true&community_sel=ARTESIA

Comment: Put a leading slash if it's the root directory. I updated the answer.

Comment: Are you sure this file exist? /residential/search_property. Because if this is itself a rewritten file then it will not work, .htaccess needs the original file to work.

Comment: Actually, this is dynamic link. If you try www.nosnownaples.com and click on  residential search and select any community from the list that url is dynamically created.

Comment: Yes but to rewrite urls the end point file must exist as a separate file. In your case /residential/search_property should exist as a file. Otherwise you need to find what is the original url.